# jpa way to see if entity or one of its relations has changed version

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpa-2.0

I'm looking for a way to find out if a detached entity has changed in the database. Furthermore I want to know if any of its relations with `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE`
has changed. The entity and some of its relations do have a version field with `@Version` annotation. Basically the test should report if a merge is going to throw an `OptimisticLockException` without trying to do the merge itself. Of course I could go through all relations and compare the version fields, but I'd like to have a more change resistant solution. So if someone adds a relation in the future the test should still work, without adopting.

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`JPA 2.0` have `Optimistic Locking` and `Pessimistic Locking`.

I think, you already know `Optimistic Locking` for main entity like as below.

[image]

**I'm looking for a way to find out if a detached entity has changed in the database?**

The below example is `Optimistic Locking` handling for detached entity. It is using `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`.

[image]